# Sending code from Sublime Text 3 to R Gui only sometimes works

Tags: r, sublimetext

I'm using Sublime Text 3 with R-box and SendCode to send selected lines to the R GUI. However, more often than not that I press `ctrl + enter` to send the code to R nothing happens. I end up pressing the command dozens of times before anything is registered.

I've pressed `ctrl + shift + p` and selected `R GUI` as the program to send code to with SendCode.

The only other settings I've changed are the following:

1. `SendCode.sublime-settings.json`

```
{
    
    "prog": "r",
    "r":
    {
        "bracketed_paste_mode": false,
        "prog": "r"
    },
    "r" : "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.0\\bin\\x64\\Rgui.exe",
}
```

2. `R-Box.sublime-settings.json`

```
{
    "rscript_binary": "C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-4.3.0\\bin\\x64\\Rscript.exe"
    }
```

On my old computer and my home on these same setting seem to send code correctly. Any ideas?

Comment: The newest version of the Sublime Text - R interface is called [`R-IDE`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/R-IDE). I would uninstall R Box and install R-IDE, then configure it properly to point to your local installation of R. I'm not an expert R developer, but I play around with it, and my initial impressions of R-IDE over R Box were quite good. I would strongly recommend using Sublime Text 4 (Build # > 4000) for full effect, although I believe it works with ST3 as well. You can check your build number via `Help -> About Sublime Text`.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I have changed R-Box for R-IDE. However, it seems they still recommend using SendCode to send lines to R, even if I've supplied the paths of both `R.exe` and `Rgui.exe` to `R-IDE`. My guess is that is where the problem lies. 

Oddly, I just deleted the `Rconsole` settings file, and it's a lot more stable. Still a few lines not being sent. 

Oh, and I'm using build 4143. Old habit of calling it ST3 I guess.

Comment: SendCode was written by the same guy that made both R-Box and R-IDE, and he even recommends SendCode in the R-IDE README, so I would assume that they should work together well. Can you figure out any kind of pattern as to what lines aren't being sent, or any other associations you can think of? Also, are any errors showing in the Sublime Console? You can open it with Ctrl-` . Also, do you get the same behavior sending lines to RStudio? This is one of those things that's very difficult to diagnose remotely, as there are so many places where settings could be off.

Comment: Yeah, they've always worked well. This is the first time simply updating paths to binaries hasn't worked. Thanks for the suggestion about the Sublime Console. I see no pattern in why some lines get sent. However, I am getting a rather generic message when lines are not sent:
`Unable to extract text from the clipboard, available formats:` and `reloading settings Packages/User/Preferences.sublime-settings`

Comment: Both of those error messages are generated by Sublime, not R-IDE or SendCode. The first one kind of makes sense, but I'm not sure why it's reloading your user preferences each time.

Comment: Okay, one more thing to try - [Safe Mode](https://www.sublimetext.com/docs/safe_mode.html). Quit Sublime, then start it from the command line in Safe Mode. Under the Tools menu, there'll be an option to install Package Control. Do that, then install *only* SendCode and R-IDE. Configure the paths, then without changing anything else see if you can replicate the behavior. If you can, it's an issue with one of the plugins. If you can't, then some other plugin or setting must be interfering with these plugins.